# enable or disable a button on another page

Tags: javascript, html

How would I be able to click a button on one page, that will enable another button on another page?

my javascript

```
function enableButton2() {
    document.getElementById("button2").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("divbutton").hidden = false;
  }
```

HTML

```
<input type="button" id="button1" value="button 1" onclick="enableButton2()"/>

<div id="divbutton" hidden>
  <input onclick="window.location.href='menu.html'" type="button" id="button2" value="button 2" disabled />
</div>
```

this code works but will only work if both these buttons are on the same page, what I'm trying to do is separate them into their own pages but still work as intended, that is clicking the first button will make the second button appear.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localStorage` would be an efficient approach if you also want to save the user's button choice. `localStorage` allows you to store a value in the same origin, which means you just have to check whether the value was changed and differentiate which button should be enabled.

For example,

```
function enableButton2() {
    localStorage.enabledButton = '2'
}
```

Then to check which button to enable, which would be used in the second page

```
setInterval(() => {
    if (localStorage.enabledButton == "1") {
        //Enable button 1
    }
    if (localStorage.enabledButton == "2") {
        //Enable button 2
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Broadcast Channel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API) to communicate between different tabs.

For example, declare the following on both pages:

```js
const bc = new BroadcastChannel('button_disable');
bc.onmessage = function(event){
    if(event.data == "hide"){
        //hide the buttons
    }else if(event.data == "show){
        //show the buttons
    }
}
```

Then, if you want to hide/show the button, simply dispatch a message:

```js
bc.postMessage('hide');
```

Comment: I would like to add.
if you have a global scrip file like "Utility.js" which you include every time it can also be in there. you would not have to duplicate code.